# Broken numpy/scipy installation (python, ubuntu 10.04)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, ubuntu-10.04

The error I'm getting is as follows:

```
$ python -c 'from sklearn import preprocessing'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/scikit_learn-0.10-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/sklearn/preprocessing/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
  from ..utils.sparsefuncs import inplace_csr_row_normalize_l1
  File "numpy.pxd", line 174, in init sklearn.utils.sparsefuncs (sklearn/utils/sparsefuncs.c:4605)
ValueError: numpy.ndarray has the wrong size, try recompiling
```

This I believe is an error with `numpy` rather than `scikitlearn` (see [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/433))

I was using the dev versions of `scipy` and `numpy` installed using git clone (and it was working fine). However I needed to "downgrade" to the stable versions for release. So I deleted the git folders, and removed the egg files from `/usr/local/lib/python-2.6/`. (To be safe) I then did:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libblas-dev liblapack-dev
$ sudo apt-get install python-dev python-numpy python-scipy
$ sudo easy_install -U distribute
$ sudo easy_install -U numpy
$ sudo easy_install -U scipy
```

Both of the last two gave me the warning ...

```
RuntimeWarning: Parent module 'numpy.distutils' not found while handling absolute import
```

... I'm not sure if that's what's going wrong here?

```
$ python -c 'import numpy; print numpy.__version__'
1.6.2

$ python -c 'import scipy; print scipy.__version__'
0.10.1
```

I've tried removing the apt installed versions but that doesn't seem to help. This is Ubuntu 10.04 (lucid) with `2.6.32-21-server` kernel

Comment: Have you recompiled scikit-learn after reinstalling numpy?

Comment: Thought I had but clearly not ... `sudo easy_install -m scikit-learn` followed by `sudo easy_install -U scikit-learn` fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest an install of the Enthought Python Distribution. Its free, installs on Ubuntu 10.04, and comes shipped with Numpy, Scipy, matplotlib, etc.

http://www.enthought.com/products/epd_free.php